# Relationship between character tables, representations, and "symmetric" solutions to summing to zero constraints

Tags: representation-theory, symmetry, characters

I would like to better understand the relationship between character tables, representations, and "symmetry arguments" when discussing "symmetric" solutions to systems like:

Consider a set of vectors we can label with the elements of some group G, that have a "symmetric" weighted sum of zero:
$$\sum_{\sigma \in G} \text{weight}(\sigma) \ v_\sigma = 0$$

I am interested in the general approach, but for sake of discussion:
Consider a set of 6 vectors we can label with the elements of $S_3$. I'll write these elements as [123],[132],[312],[321],[231],[213].

The only kind of symmetry argument I easily understand currently is a parity argument. That is, if vectors obey: v_[123] = - v_[132], and similarly for other parity swaps, then I can clearly argue:
$$\sum_{\sigma \in S_3} \text{parity}(\sigma) \ v_\sigma = 0$$

But that involved simple pairwise cancellation: v_[123] + v_[132] = 0. In otherwords it was due to a "simpler" symmetry in the set: pairing them up and labeling the pairs by elements of Z_2.

There are probably other "symmetric" solutions that cannot be broken down this way, where some "term" in v_[123] that is cancelled by -v_[132], such that the full "weighted sum" above is still zero but pairwise v_[123], v_[132] do not sum to zero.

How can I systematically explore these possibilities?

And I definitely am at a loss when I see there are representations of dimension > 1. For example S_3 has dimension 2 reps, what is that saying for how the vectors should be related or how I weight them in a sum? Maybe complex numbers? But then what about groups with dimension 3 reps?

I'm sure this is a large and deep topic, but I am primarily interested in how I can look at a character table and figure out what different "symmetric" possible solutions to such a sum may look like.

I'm currently trying to solve a problem with polynomials with a bizarre kind of symmetry, and I think they sum to zero given the right kind of "symmetric sum". But beyond a parity argument, I have no idea what these could look like, so I have no idea what I should be trying to prove about the relationship of these polynomials. An engineering friend suggested I learn about symmetry tables and while this definitely looks like a useful path, I'm struggling to figure out how to use this information.

Comment: I assume you're trying to find the vector functions $G\to\Bbb R^n$ (or $\Bbb C^n$) that make the weighted sum zero? If the weight function is a scalar function with no group-theoretic interpretation, then this is just a linear algebra problem that has nothing to do with $G$ being a group. And indeed the answer would come from putting the column vectors into a matrix, and picking each row from the orthogonal complement of the weight vector.

Comment: What exactly is a "parity swap"? Do you mean replacing a permutation of one parity by literally any permutation of the other parity? If so, an alternating vector $v_\sigma$ only takes two values, $v$ for even permutations and $-v$ for odd permutations, in which case $\sum v_\sigma=0$ and (contrary to your post) $\sum ({\rm sgn}\sigma)v_\sigma=n!v$. The analogous situation is that if $v_\sigma$ is identically $v$, then $\sum v_\sigma=n!v$ and $\sum({\rm sgn}\sigma)v_\sigma=0$.

Comment: And what do representations have to do with your problem? Are you considering the weight function taking matrix values (i.e. being a representation) instead of a scalar function? Or are you supposing the vectors themselves are matrix values $\rho(g)$ of a representation, and you're trying to find the scalar weights $w(g)$? Or else how are representations relevant?